# Filling a dropdownlist dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, listbox

So I'm working in ASP.NET MVC4 and I want to load a dropdownlist dynamically.

This is my modelclass:

```
public class Meeting
{
public int MeetingId { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A name is required")]
public String Name { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
public String Location { get; set; }
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A start date is required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DateGreaterThan("StartDate")]
public DateTime? EndDate  { get; set; }

public int? CountryId { get; set; }
public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
public String Sport { get; set; }

public List<string> SelectedTeamIds { get; set; }
public virtual List<TeamViewModel> SelectedTeams { get; set; }

public List<int> SelectedEventIds { get; set; }
public virtual List<EventViewModel> SelectedEvents { get; set; }



   public Meeting()
   {
    SelectedTeamIds = new List<string>();
    SelectedTeams = new List<TeamViewModel>();

    SelectedEventIds = new List<int>();
    SelectedEvents = new List<EventViewModel>(); 
    }
}
```

This is my controllermethod I'm interested in :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.CountryId = new MultiSelectList(db.Countries, "CountryId", "CountryName");
  ViewBag.AvailableEvents = db.Events.Where(e => e.SchoolcupEvent == true);
  ViewBag.AvailableTeams = db.Teams;
  var model = new Meeting();
  return View(model);
}
```

And this is the view of this method:

```
@model Project.Domain.POCO.Meeting

<h2>Create</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Meeting</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayName("Country")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", "Pick a country")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayName("Start Date")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DisplayName("End Date")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
    </div>
     <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Sports type")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sport, "Swimming" ) Swimming
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sport, "Athletics" ) Athletics
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Select Event(s)")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedEventIds, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.AvailableEvents, "EventId", "Discipline", Model.SelectedEventIds), new { @class = "superselect" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Select Team(s)")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedTeamIds, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.AvailableTeams, "TeamId", "TeamId", Model.SelectedTeamIds), new { @class = "superselect" })
    </div>
    <p class="Button">
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Css/UserInterface.css")
}
```

A meeting consists of a number of events.
So the problem is at the ListBox with events, how can I dynamically load only the events that belong to the meeting I selected earlier. I have done some research on the allmighty Google, but all I'm getting are answers involving javascript/jquery, and since my knowledge is basically 0 about that, I had hoped to solve this in another way if possible. If not, could you explain to me simply what I need to do, and what I'm doing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the easiest way is to use jquery see http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/dynamically-populate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: That doesn't really explain what I want to achieve though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to realize it without jquery or javascript. If want to use ASP.NET MVC you should become familiar with jquery, its vital.
For your here some hints that might help:

- the *change* of selection of the 1st dropdown is an event that can be
  catched by jquery
- a jquery function can *post* the selected value to
  the server and receive the relevant data for the 2nd dropdown.
- the 2nd dropdown can be filled by *append* options to the empty dropdown. If the 2nd dropdown depends on the selection of the 1st dropdown you don't have to fill it in the first place. But you have to *remove all* items (options) each time the selection of the 1st dropdown changes

However, there is another option called ASP.NET Webforms where you can define the eventhandling with help of VS-tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid jquery all together and use the LiteralControl Class.

[ASP.NET MVC`s LiteralControl Class.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx)